# why is jQTouch served as application/x-javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, jqtouch

I've always wondered why any jQTouch files are served with the mime type "application/x-javascript" as opposed to "text/javascript". Is there a particular reason for this I wonder, or is it just for accuracy's sake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to clear the confusion:

- [Javascript MIME type](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/02/javascript-mime-type)

> There has always been confusion on the
>   official MIME type of javascript.
>   While servers mostly seem to use the
>   following Apache rule: **AddType
>   application/x-javascript** **.js authors
>   claim it is text/javascript** in the
>   TYPE attribute of the SCRIPT element
>   (if they declare it). That has
>   multiple reasons. **First of all, the
>   HTML specification suggests
>   text/javascript and
>   application/x-javascript is not
>   supported by Internet Explorer. Note
>   that IE does not support it only if it
>   is the value of the TYPE attribute,
>   what the server sends does not seem to
>   matter.**
>
> And it gets even better. While the
>   HTML camp is happily referring to
>   their .js served as
>   **application/x-javascript using
>   text/javascript as value for the TYPE
>   attribute SVG people are using
>   text/ecmascript.** And again, this is
>   because the SVG specification suggests
>   it.
>
> Perhaps, in the near future this will
>   all be over when the draft of
>   Scripting Media Types (01) becomes a
>   RFC. Eventually it will specify two
>   media types. (Currently it lists
>   four.) One for javascript and one for
>   ECMAScript. From a theoretical point
>   of view I hope application/javascript
>   and application/ecmascript will
>   survive to the end. However,
>   text/javascript and text/ecmascript
>   are probably more useful with regard
>   to current implementations and
>   specifications.

Comment: hmm, I was wondering if it was an implementation issue, i.e. that mobile webkit has problems with it. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: ah, so the reason we all tend to use "text/javascript" is for IE's sake!

Comment: @Aaron: Yup that seems to be so :)